excel vba assign value to variable with all styles
The code is performing a copy from area Q145:AE211 on button click and pasting in a continues way to next cells after each button click. The problem is that area Q145:AE211 without data contains also all styles for cells - colors, borders, customised cell width and also merged cells formatting. Right now it copies only data. How to assign to "arr" everything else besides "value"?
 Dim lastCol As Long, arr

 arr = Range("Q145:AE211").Value
 
 lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 16
 
 Cells(1, lastCol).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
 
 End Sub



sure, array is an array, im fresh in excel and thinking about workarounds. Every time I do copy/paste styles, like in your provided example, and assign it to area before arr data is inserted, the arr considers it as already "taken"area and just copies data after styled area. So its a no - that question does not provide answer to my case.

Yes, 16 so to copy data not one above other but nicely displaying one after other, because data is 15 cells long. If i take 16 out or change, it does not add any styles. My question is normal and its suggested for closing based on short problems impression.

Try this way, but I don't understand why you add 16?
Sub TestCopy()
   Dim lastCol As Long
   Range("Q145:AE211").Copy
   lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 16   ' why 16 ???
   Cells(1, lastCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   Cells(1, lastCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


16 is because 15 cells of data and +1 for space, the macro is activated every time button is clicked so the idea is that the new data from Q145:AE211 is copied every time next to previous one (15 length) and space between them. Your solution copied with all styles first time (great!), for next it gives error "we can't do that to a merged cell". Yes, the area Q145:AE211 contains merged cells.

It is strange with this 16. Maybe your first row is merged or nearly empty and only first column in each block is filled. There are always problems with merged cells. You should avoid them before work is almost finished. I don't know where the problem is because I don't see your sheet and position of these merged cells.

This is a snipet of my code, that pastes values and formats, not sure if it'll work for you.
    Sub CopyPasteRange

Range("B4:H60").Select         
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False 
End Sub


To add: I'm not sure why you would assign the copied range to a variable, but I'm not that familiar with VBA, so there's probably a valid reason to do that.

I do that because in my case it is able to copy data one after other detecting next free cell. Im complete newbie in excel and this solution works for my use case, but sure there is no styles for array, I thought maybe experts know some workaround how to add styles as well.
